# PostgreSQL stored procedure to return rows or empty set

Tags: postgresql, functions, dynamic-sql, plpgsql

I have a stored procedure, which `RETURNS SETOF ct_custom_type` and inside I do

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'some dynamic query'
```

And I want to do this: If this 'dynamic query' returns >= 10 rows, I want to return them, but if it returns only < 10 rows, I don't want to return anything (empty set of `ct_custom_type`).

I tried:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'some dynamic query'

GET DIAGNOSTICS variable = ROW_COUNT;
IF variable < 10 THEN

    # I don't know what to do here or how to accomplish this

END IF;
```

If I do `RETURN QUERY SELECT 0, 0, ''::text;` in the `IF` block (because `ct_custom_type` is a composite type of `(integer, integer, text)`, it just adds this 'empty row' to previous query result, but I don't want to return anything in this case, I can do `RETURN;`, but it will return that previous result and I want to discard it.

I have it like this:

```
EXECUTE 'dynamic query';

GET DIAGNOSTICS variable = ROW_COUNT;
IF variable >= 10 THEN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'dynamic query';
END IF;
```

and it works, but I didn't want to do this query two times.

Comment: That's actually a *very* interesting question.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something along the following lines:

```
test=> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION temptabl(cnt integer)
RETURNS SETOF integer AS
$body$
BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_container ON COMMIT DROP AS
    SELECT a
    FROM generate_series(1, cnt) t(a);

    IF (SELECT count(1) FROM tmp_container) > 5
    THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT a FROM tmp_container;
    END IF;
END;
$body$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


test=> SELECT * FROM temptabl(4);
 temptabl 
----------
(0 rows)

test=> SELECT * FROM temptabl(6);
 temptabl 
----------
        1
        2
        3
        4
        5
        6
(6 rows)
```

This way you have to perform your original query only once.  All other statements work on the temporary table.

Comment: You might be interested in my added answer since I am referring to yours.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I am always wondering how you keep finding these ancient questions :)

Comment: Mostly by looking for possible dupes of new questions or for a prior art I can link to in my answers. This time while tagging some typical questions with `set-returning-functions`. :)

Answer (score 8):

#### The return set

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING-RETURN-NEXT)

> `RETURN NEXT` and `RETURN QUERY` do not actually return from the function
> — they simply append zero or more rows to the function's result set.
> Execution then continues with the next statement in the PL/pgSQL
> function. As successive `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` commands are
> executed, the result set is built up. A final `RETURN`, which should
> have no argument, causes control to exit the function (or you can just
> let control reach the end of the function).

#### Raise `EXCEPTION` instead

So you can cancel the operation by raising an `EXCEPTION` and the client won't get any rows.
Won't get cheaper than that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_min_records(min_ct integer = 10)  -- default minimum 10
  RETURNS SETOF tbl
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   row_ct int;
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'some dynamic query (matching return type)';

   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_ct = ROW_COUNT;

   IF row_ct < min_ct THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Only % rows! Requested minimum was %.', row_ct, min_ct;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

Call (for default minimum of 10 rows):

```
SELECT * FROM f_min_records_wrapper();
```

We included a [code example in the manual for that (`get_available_flightid()`)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40216/3684).

#### Don't raise `EXCEPTION`

To my knowledge, the only way to keep the return set from actually being returned is to raise an exception. If you don't want to raise an exception, either, you are in a bit of a pickle with current PL/pgSQL.

If you [trap the `EXCEPTION`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c027/2) in the same function, the result set is still returned. I tried and failed to solve it with a [nested block][4]. Doesn't seem to make any difference for the return set.

**But** you can nest the function call in an outer function and catch the exception there. That works just as desired.

**In addition** to the extended function from above:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_min_records(min_ct integer = 10)  -- default minimum 10
  RETURNS SETOF t
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   row_ct int;
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT * from t';   -- some dynamic query (matching return type)

   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_ct = ROW_COUNT;

   IF row_ct < min_ct THEN
      RAISE SQLSTATE 'BRRRR'   -- 5 ASCII chars
      USING MESSAGE = format('Only %s rows! Requested minimum was %s.', row_ct, min_ct);
   END IF;

END
$func$;
```

Create a wrapper function, which you actually call:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_min_records_wrapper(min_ct integer = 10)
  RETURNS SETOF t
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT * from f_min_records(min_ct);

EXCEPTION 
   WHEN SQLSTATE 'BRRRR' THEN
   RAISE NOTICE '%', SQLERRM;  -- optionally pass error msg
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_min_records_wrapper(17);
```

#### Alternative with temp table

Same basic idea like in [deszo's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/40216/3684), but avoid separate count, plus other features:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_temptbl(min_ct integer = 10)
  RETURNS SETOF t
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   row_ct int;
BEGIN
   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _temptbl;                      -- for mult. calls in 1 transaction
   CREATE TEMP TABLE _temptbl (LIKE t) ON COMMIT DROP; -- match RETURNS type

   EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO _temptbl SELECT * FROM t';     -- text with dyn SQL

   GET DIAGNOSTICS row_ct = ROW_COUNT;

   IF row_ct >= min_ct THEN
      RETURN QUERY TABLE _temptbl;
   END IF;
END
$func$;
```

[**SQL Fiddle** demonstrating all.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0c027/2)

#### Feature Wish - non-existent at least up to pg 16

A command to cancel the return set would be marvelous:

```
RETURN CANCEL;
```

Or maybe even with an optional number of rows to "roll back" (default being all):

```
RETURN CANCEL 10;
```